# Order array of hashes by another array

Tags: ruby, arrays, csv, hash

I got 2 arrays one array of hashes another array of keys. I need to make array of hashes to be in same order as array of keys. How can I do it

```
header = ["header1", "header2", "header3", "header4", "header5"]
record = [{"header4" =>"value4"}, {"header3" =>"value3"}, {"header5"=>"value5"}, {"header1"=>"value1"}, {"header2"=>"value2"}]
```

I need array record to put in the same order as array the header

```
record = [{"header1" =>"value1"}, {"header2" =>"value2"}, {"header3"=>"value3"}, {"header4"=>"value4"}, {"header5"=>"value5"}]
```

Thank you very much to every one for the help. I want to add one more question to this post.
I am trying to use methods suggested below  to create CSV document from database. So I want to organise columns in particular order and I have template of this order and this template stored as array of headers but when I doing

```
csv<< mymodel.attributes.values.sort_by! { |h| header.index(h.keys[0])
```

It does not work

Comment: Please ask your follow-up question in a new StackOverflow question. Accept an answer below for your original question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Array#sort_by!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-sort_by-21) / [`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) accept a block. The return value of the block is used for comparison. For your case, you can use [`Array#index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-index).

```
header = ["header1", "header2", "header3", "header4", "header5"]
record = [{"header4" =>"value4"}, {"header3" =>"value3"},
          {"header5"=>"value5"}, {"header1"=>"value1"},
          {"header2"=>"value2"}]
record.sort_by! { |h| header.index(h.keys[0]) }
# => [{"header1"=>"value1"}, {"header2"=>"value2"}, {"header3"=>"value3"},
#     {"header4"=>"value4"}, {"header5"=>"value5"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it as @falsetru has done, but here's another way:

```
record.each_with_object({}) { |h,g| g[h.keys.first] = h }.values_at(*header)
  #=> [{"header1"=>"value1"}, {"header2"=>"value2"}, {"header3"=>"value3"},
  #    {"header4"=>"value4"}, {"header5"=>"value5"}]
```

Comment: very nice. The logic is a bit confusing as to readability (not your fault at all) but the conciseness is beautiful. Although I would use `keys.find{|k| k=~ /header/ }` in place of `.first` in case the keys are not sorted in this order in every `Hash`.

Comment: @engineersmnky, I agree with you re readability, which is the main reason I prefer the use of `sort_by`, `index`.

Answer (score 0):

For this simple object you don't really need the additional array as this will work

```
record.sort_by do |hash| 
  hash.keys.find{|key| key=~ /header/}.scan(/\d+/).pop.to_i
end
#=> [{"header1"=>"value1"}, {"header2"=>"value2"}, {"header3"=>"value3"}, {"header4"=>"value4"}, {"header5"=>"value5"}]
```

I have a feeling though that this question was stripped down to the essentials but thought I would show you anyway. Since you just want to sort by the header number this will find the header key then `scan` for numbers pop out the last one and convert to `Integer` for sorting. so it will work for any `Hash` with keys like `"header1"` or `"header1432"`

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are all great, but none perform the operation in O(n) time. I think the theoretical performance and clarity can be improved by turning `results` into a temporary hash:

```
>> record_h = record.reduce(:merge)
=> {"header4"=>"value4", "header3"=>"value3", "header5"=>"value5", "header1"=>"value1", "header2"=>"value2"}
```

-

```
>> header.map{|h| {h => record_h[h]}}
=> [{"header1"=>"value1"}, {"header2"=>"value2"}, {"header3"=>"value3"}, {"header4"=>"value4"}, {"header5"=>"value5"}]
```